# Deploying a react app on hosting platforms (github pages, netlify)

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, github-pages, netlify, npm-package

I have created a portfolio website using react, `create-react-app` with typescript template. I was trying to deploy it on github pages following [this](https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages), but I keep getting an error `you need to enable Javascript on your browser`. I have tried following several things but nothing really works, it just shows a blank white page.

After this I tried Netlify, it starts the deployment but fails on a local package that must be installed. I was trying to use a react package from npm which was missing a customisation so I made the changes in code and use the build as a local npm package in my source code.
Error:  `Module not found: Error: Can"t resolve "react-chrono" in "/opt/build/repo/src/timeline"`.

I can run and build it fine on my machine.

[Link](https://github.com/kumar-nilesh-101/kumar-nilesh-101.github.io) to my github repository.

**TLDR; Deploying a react app on github pages or netlify(when you have a local npm package).**

Comment: Why don't you publish your local package to npm website?

Comment: @Nikolay Because it is not my developement, just a minor tweak in an existing package

Comment: You can always submit a pull request for the existing package. If not feasible, you can publish your own version anyway, there are tons of clones. Or you can incorporate a build of that package into the GH actions build.

Comment: @Nikolay, thanks I'll keep this in mind next time, I have solved this though

Answer (score 0):

Anyone trying it on [github pages](https://%20https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages), in your `package.json` file set the `homepage` property to `'.'` instead of `https://{username}.github.io`. If you try and run the static build locally and check index.html, all stylesheet and script paths start with your homepage and it mess up the imports.